# How to use a struct inside another struct (while using malloc and 2D arrays?) in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I am new to using struct, hope you can help me. I want to have a nested struct such that a member of A is type B struct. The code I have so far is shown below.

```
typedef struct B
{
   int b1;
} b;

typedef struct A
{
    b a1;
}a;
```

But I also need 'a1' to be a dynamic 2d array, so I did the following code (not sure if this is right as i used a pointer to a pointer for this in order for the 'array' size to be set at runtime):

```
typedef struct B
{
   int b1;
} b;

typedef struct A
{
    b **a1;
}a;
```

To store memory I used malloc(didnt include the error detection part). I need to refer and compare each member of a1 by x, shown below (where a and b are integers). Can I do this?:

```
a* one;
b** two;

one= malloc(10* sizeof(a*));
two= malloc(10* sizeof(b*));
for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        two[x] = malloc(10* sizeof(b));
    }

 if(one[x].two[a][b] == x)
    one[x].two[a][b].b1 =2;
```

Sorry if my code doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: The expression b **a1 is not a 2d array. It is a pointer to a variable that holds a pointer.

Comment: To add to what @clarasoft-it wrote: It cannot even be use as a 2D array, nor point to one. There are enough Q&A here which show how to allocate a 2D array and handle it. Read them, it is much easier to handle.

Comment: I got it! so basically unless x is of type b it is not going to work. So I just added another member to b, int b2, to be able to make a similar comparison

Comment: @ clarasoft-it, yes you're right. since I couldn't make a 2d array in struct, i used a pointer to a pointer... It seems to be working just as well

Comment: Any reason you use `struct A` anyway? Or use a `struct` tag although you `typedef` your structs anyway? And **please** use more explanatory names for types! something like `A` or `a` should not be even used for a global variable, less a type (or function).

Comment: @Olaf is doing the 2d array you mentioned better than the use of pointers when used inside struct?

Comment: @J.DOLE: I did not say you should not use a pointer. Just not a pointer to a pointer, but a pointer to an array.

Comment: @Olaf was hoping to make the code more simple than the one i already had hence the A, but i guess that confused it more. sorry about that. The use of typedef was so that i dont write struct all the time

Comment: I did not question `typedef`ing, just there is no need for the tags and using self-explanatory names (in general). Using a 2D array definitively would make the code3 easier. That's one reason I do recommend it.

Comment: Perhaps taking a look at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) on variable length arrays could shed a bit of light too.

Comment: @Olaf I will definitely take your advise. Having 2D arrays would probably help make my code easier for me to understand too.

Comment: @Olaf 2D arrays are not suitable for my code as  I need the 'arrays' to be dynamic... what i mean is that i need to set their size at run time

Comment: @J.DOLE: And where is the problem? You already got a link to Wikipedia for VLAs!

Comment: `for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++)` is a problem.  Use `for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also need 'a1' to be a 2d array, so I did the following code (not
>   sure if this is right):
>
> ```
> typedef struct B
> {
>    int b1;
> } b;
>
> typedef struct A
> {
>     b **a1;
> }a;
> ```

The code provides valid C declarations, but there is no 2d array in sight.  Member `a1` of `struct A` is a pointer to pointer to `struct B`, which is not at all the same thing.  If you truly want to declare a 2d array then you must give its bounds, for instance

```
typedef struct A {
    b a1[5][7];
} a;
```

If you don't know the needed sizes until runtime, however, then the double pointer is indeed what you want -- just do not confuse it with a 2D array.

> To store memory I used malloc(didnt include the error detection part). I need to refer and compare each member of a1 by x, shown below (where a and b are integers).

Well no, `a` and `b` cannot be integers because you're already using them as type names in the same scope.

> Can I do this?:
>
> ```
> a* one;
> b** two;
>
> one= malloc(10* sizeof(a*));
> two= malloc(10* sizeof(b*));
> for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
>     {
>         two[x] = malloc(10* sizeof(b));
>     }
> ```

In addition to the name collision already mentioned, your allocation of `one` is wrong.  It should be ...

```
 one = malloc(10 * sizeof(a));
```

... or even better ...

```
 one = malloc(10 * sizeof(*one));
```

.  Your allocations for `two` and `two[x]` are ok, but they would be better if rewritten in the same manner as my latter example above.

> ```
>  if(one[x].two[a][b] == x)
>     one[x].two[a][b].b1 =2;
> ```

The type of `one[x].two[i][j]` (for integer `i` and `j`) is `b`, which is to say `struct B`.  The type of `x` is `int`.  These are not comparable, so no, you cannot evaluate the expression in the `if` condition.  The assignment to `one[x].two[a][b].b1` is ok, though.

Comment: THANK YOU! This really helps. I was already changing my code to have 2D arrays as @Olaf previously suggested. I thought I simply overlooked a way to set the array size at run time, so thank you for clarifying. Thanks also for correcting my mistake for the allocations

Comment: just a quick question... don't  I require a* for allocation of one, since one is an array?      I am referring to this line of code: one= malloc(10* sizeof(a*));

Comment: @J.DOLE.  No.  The type of `one` is `a *`.  You need to reserve space in multiples of the size of the pointed-to things, which in this case is `sizeof(a)`.  But you can spell "the size of the thing `one` points to" more clearly as `sizeof(*one)`, which is especially appropriate when allocating memory.  That also has the benefit that it does not need to be changed if you ever change the type of `one`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing around with 2D dynamic memory allocation, you can fake a 2D array with a 1D array.

```
b *a1;
a1 = malloc(sizeof(b) * width * height);
for(i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < width; j++)
        do_stuff(a1[i*width + j];  //simulates a1[i][j]
```

The only thing this requires is that you store your width and height values somewhere, eg

```
typedef struct A {
    b *a1;
    int height;
    int width;
}
```

Comment: And what is that worth for? Any reason OP should not use a 2D array? (That might make sense with a FAM, though, but you don't show that).

Comment: It allows OP to dynamically allocate a "2D" array without going into any of the weird complexity that would confuse a new programmer. It's not any less efficient than a 2D array, just slightly more difficult to read.

Comment: `It's not any less efficient than a 2D array` is not defined so by C.  Without a built-in multiply (think low-end embedded processors), this code is noticeably less efficient.